# expect abstract class with default argument doesn't generate $default static method

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Let's say I have a class like below:

```
abstract class AbsTest {
    fun test(k: String, v: String? = null) {
        println("Key - $k, Value - $v")
    }
}
```

And a class which inherits from it:

```
class Test : AbsTest { ... }
```

My main function looks something like this:

```
fun main() {
    Test().test("Hello")
}
```

This works absolutely fine. However, if I do this in Kotlin Multi-platform, then it fails. Here is my KMP code:

```
expect abstract class AbsTest {
    fun test(k: String, v: String? = null)
}

// Android Target
actual abstract class AbsTest {
    fun test(k: String, v: String?) { ... }
}

class Test : AbsTest { ... }

// Calling Place
fun finalTest() {
    Test().test("Hello")
}
```

The above KMP code throws below exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method test$default(...) in class AbsTest found
```

Out of curiosity, when I decompiled the code to check the generated bytecode, I found the problem that it doesn't generate the $default method for KMP project where as the other one works fine.

Decompiled code (normal Kotlin project)

```
public abstract class AbsTest {
    public final void test(@NotNull String k, @Nullable String v) {
        ...
    }
    public static void test$default(AbsTest var0, String var1, String var2, int var3, Object var4) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Decompiled code (KMP project)

```
public abstract class AbsTest {
    public final void test(@NotNull String k, @Nullable String v) {
        ...
    }
    // No test$default() method generated
}
```

Any reason why KMP behaves this way? How to fix this?

Comment: Looks like a bug? According to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21913 it's supposed to be supported (+ https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34823 says "If someFun is not suspend, it works just fine"), so it may be specific to your case and should be reported there especially if you can make a small reproduction.

Comment: Looks like the issue (with suspend fun) was fixed - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24461

Answer (score 0):

You already found the problem as you stated. The kotlin compiler somehow doesn't compile the default methods. How ever, as a workarround, you can have two different methods as follows.

```
expect abstract class AbsTest {
    // fun test(k: String, v: String? = null)
    fun test(k: String)
    fun test(k: String,v: String?)
}

// Android Target
actual abstract class AbsTest {
    fun test(k: String) { . . .}
    fun test(k: String, v: String?) {
        if(v==null){
            test(k);
        }
        . . .
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's workaround. But can't be the real solution. Because this solution defeats the purpose of default argument feature provided by Kotlin.